# Procedure Output

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

If I have created a procedure and that procedure return 98 rows and last 2 rows it won't return due to some issue. How I'll check which rows it won't return and how to resolve?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbms_output to print on console which rows have not been returned. 
Remember to write `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;` within your procedure as the first line.

Example:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
IF condition THEN
   --statements that return 98 rows    
ELSE
   dbms_output.put_line('not returned when id = '|| id);

END IF;
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036) you can read more about it in PL/SQL

Comment: Could you please give me  an example by using this ?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to my answer.